# Conditional SELECT SQL with relational tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have an id in table1 which is a foreign key in table2 and there is a column in table2 called condition.

I need to select all ids from table 1 that aren't in table2 where condition = 1.

So for id in table 1 "select it" if it is not in table2 where condition = 1.

Edit: I used Ahsan Habib's answer and it worked great!

Comment: In that case, you should accept his answer :-) -- there should be a check mark to the left of the answer itself, near the "upvote" triangle.

Comment: How do I do that? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to select ID column from table1 this will work fine....Its just a simple set operation

`select id from t1
minus 
select id from t2 where condition = 1;`

for all column you may try

`select * from t1 whare id not in (select id from t2 where condition = 1);`

Comment: I like your style but surely `mysql` doesn't have a `minus` operator?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a direct translation of what you are asking for:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.id not in (select t2.id from table2 t2 where t2.condition = 1);
```

Comment: select t1.* from table1 t1, I normally do select id from table1 why did you do it like that? I am fairly new to SQL so would appreciate it :) Also what is t1?

Comment: @CaseyMiddleton - `t1.*` just select all the columns from `table1` table

Comment: Cause I did it this way

    select *
    from table1
    where table1.id not in (select id from table2 where condition = 1); baring in mind I am doing this by pymysql, is it doing the t1.* stuff for me?

Comment: @Prdp Er okay, cause I just did select * from table1, why did he do it that way instead?

Comment: @CaseyMiddleton `t1` is alias name of `table1`. Simply he kept `Select t1.*` it is same as `Select *` `t1.*`. It will make difference when you have another table Joined.

Comment: @Prdp Ah okay, thank you. Also if you want to for other users change your @'s to my new username please :)

Comment: @Artuki . . . I use `select *`, because the `select` is not relevant to what  you need to answer the question.  Listing the columns can be a distraction from seeing how the query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where NOT EXISTS(select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t2.condition = 1);
```